# Laravel 5 href route

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

any chance someone could explain to me how if for example I'm on 
http://localhost:8000/sales/create and I have a nav link that points to "sales/create" how I would go about structuring things so page is not directed to "sales/sales/create" when the link is clicked.

Apologies if the question is not clear.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to just give a `name` to my `route` and then reference it with:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('sales/create' }}"> Create Sale </a>
```

Then in your route, you would provide the `name` as an argument:

```
Route::get('/sales/create', array(
    'name' => 'sales/create',
    'controller' => 'SalesController@create'
));
```

If you would prefer not to do this, then just make sure that the path is `absolute` as opposed to `relative`.

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/sales/create') }}"> Create Sale </a>
```

Note the leading `/` in front of `sales`.

Comment: For the first example there is no need to use URL:: laravel 5.1 has a set of function where one is 'route('name.of.route')' and if not mistaking also 'route()->to('/');'